# Missing XCM benchmark `reserve_asset_deposited`

Tags: polkadot, xcm, benchmarking

I'm upgrading our `parachain` based on Polkadot 0.9.40 [here](https://github.com/NodleCode/chain/pull/735). Now in the process of benchmarking xcm operations, I notice there is no benchmark for `reserve_asset_deposited` in XCM fungible benchmarks! I wonder how is it then benchmarked in Kusama and some other places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work is being done in this PR:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/7077

Relevant issue:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/7167